# laravel response status -1 on mobile

Tags: php, laravel, http, angular-http, http-error

I'm developing an applicaiton using laravel 5.2, and using angular in some places on the front end. I'm always getting -1 as the response status for `$http` requests,  when testing with mobile. The same functions are working in desktop without a problem. There's no way for me to see the network tab since it's the mobile phone. I'm testing with iPhone SE and Samsung Grand Prime Pro (Android).

Comment: Have you pass response status with api??

Comment: How about testing it on iPhone Simulator, and use desktop safari on your (I assume) macbook to debug?

Comment: Share your any api code